# Problems with relative import

Tags: python, cython, python-import, pytorch

I run a file called `test.py` which has an import like this

```
from .nms.cpu_nms import cpu_nms, cpu_soft_nms
from .nms.gpu_nms import gpu_nms
```

When I run the file though, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    from utils.nms_wrapper import nms
  File /media/ryan/shakira/InsightFace_Pytorch/FaceBoxes.PyTorch/utils/nms_wrapper.py",     line 7, in <module>
    from .nms.cpu_nms import cpu_nms, cpu_soft_nms
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.nms.cpu_nms'
```

I have tried doing

`sys.path.append('/path/to/the/main/directory/')`

But that too does not work,

EDIT:

This is my directory structure:

```
FaceBoxes.PyTorch/
├── data
│   ├── AFW
│   │   └── img_list.txt
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── data_augment.py
│   ├── FDDB
│   │   └── img_list.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── PASCAL
│   │   └── img_list.txt
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── config.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── data_augment.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wider_voc.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── WIDER_FACE
│   │   └── img_list.txt
│   └── wider_voc.py
├── layers
│   ├── functions
│   │   ├── prior_box.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── prior_box.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── multibox_loss.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │       └── multibox_loss.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── __pycache__
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── LICENSE
├── make.sh
├── models
│   ├── faceboxes.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── test.py
├── train.py
└── utils
    ├── box_utils.py
    ├── build.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── nms
    │   ├── cpu_nms.c
    │   ├── cpu_nms.pyx
    │   ├── gpu_nms.cpp
    │   ├── gpu_nms.hpp
    │   ├── gpu_nms.pyx
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── nms_kernel.cu
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── py_cpu_nms.py
    ├── nms_wrapper.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── box_utils.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── nms_wrapper.cpython-36.pyc
    └── timer.py
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `from nms.cpu_nms import cpu_nms, cpu_soft_nms`. Remove `.` before the name of library.

Comment: It would be helpful to know a bit more about your directory structure where things like `test.py` the `nms` module are located. It would also be helpful to know how you invoke your program (eg. `python test.py` or otherwise).

Comment: Hi @Heyran.rs Sorry for the late response,  i tried that, it gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nms'`

Comment: @Dunes I habe updated the question with more directory info

Comment: Please clarify your python version. Relative imports works different between 2.x and 3.x. I recommend to take time for this [David Beazley presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/modulepackage)

Comment: Im using python.3.5, also Thanks for the link

Comment: Please clarify: a)your `test.py` (as in tree listing) is outside of `utils`. Maybe you need `import utils.nms.cpu_nms`  in this case? b) what are `*cpython-36.pyc` files are doing in your `__pycache__`s if you are using `python-3.5`?

Comment: It doesn't look like you compiled the `nms` module. You have `.pyx` files, but no `.so` or `.pyd` files. Since you've included all the `.pyc` files i would expect to see these.

Comment: A quick look at https://github.com/zisianw/FaceBoxes.PyTorch suggests you need to run `make.sh` first. Check the readme for more information -- https://github.com/zisianw/FaceBoxes.PyTorch/blob/master/README.md#installation

Comment: @Dunes Thanks a lot, Ill be more careful when going through a repo.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? If so: can you post a solution as answer?

Comment: @AlexYu Yes, i solved it, ill post the solution in some time

Comment: Relative imports are common source of confusion. And I suppose that your question must be tagged with `pytorch` and `cython` too.

Answer (score 0):

There was no error in the imports, The problem was that there was a cython file which i had to compile which i had glossed over.And once i had compiled,the problem disappeared.

Comment: So it's a `cython` problem too?